# Find the differrence between employees' salaries and sort by highest to lowest

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this:

```
NAME           SALARY
Gareth         37451000.7
Lorah          2426222.55
Sage           2910000.98
```

I would like to find the difference between each employee's salary, sorted by highest to lowest difference? Like this...

```
NAME          name            salary diff
Sage          Lorah          483778.43
Sage          Gareth         -34540999.72
Lorah         Gareth         -35024778.15
```

How do I go about coding this result? Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried already? What, exactly, are you stuck on? Also, what version of SQL Server are you on (lag is 2012+ i believe)?

Comment: I have tried the following so far...

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, Why `lag`? I thought it requires `cross join`.

Comment: `Select A.NAME, B.NAME, (A.SALARY - B.SALARY) as 'salary diff"
FROM Employee A, Employee B
WHERE A.NAME <> B.NAME AND A.SALARY < B.SALARY`

Comment: Don't add code in comments [edit] your question

Comment: But instead of Sage and Lorah's result being a positive number, it's a negative...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your requirements, here a solution

```
declare @report table(Id int identity(1,1),
                  Name varchar(20),
                  Salary money)
insert into @report(Name,Salary)
select 'Gareth' as Name,37451000.7 as Salary
union all
select 'Lorah' as Name,2426222.55 as Salary
union all
select 'Sage' as Name,2910000.98 as Salary

select p.Name,r.Name as SName, p.Salary - r.Salary as [Diff]
from @report r
inner join @report p on r.Name <> p.Name and r.Id<p.Id
```

here the output result

```
Name    SName   Diff
Lorah   Gareth  -35024778.15
Sage    Gareth  -34540999.72
Sage    Lorah   483778.43
```

best regards

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    a.Name
    ,b.Name
    ,a.salary - b.salary as 'Salary Difference'
FROM #salary a 
JOIN #salary b 
    ON a.name != b.name 
    AND b.id < a.id
```

Comment: Yes, it came up in the review queue as it was your first post. Just making it easier on the eye so it's easier to understand.

Comment: @RichBenner Thank you.